# How to find and disambiguate a union type from a list of union types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a basic union type;

```
    type A = {type: "A"}
    type B = {type: "B"}
    type X =  A | B
```

And I have a function that finds an item in a list that has the same type:

```
    function find(x: X, list: Array<X>) {
        return list.find(item => item.type === x.type)
    }
```

I would expect the return type of this function to be the specific subtype of X that matches the input x. That is, I want `find({type: "A"}, [{type: "A"}, {type: "B"}])` to return a type of A.

Any ideas how I might do this?

---

Edit: It turns out what I'm dealing with is a little more complicated. I have a concept of batches that are queue and I want to add an item to a batch if it exists, otherwise I want to enqueue a new batch:

```
    type A = { type: "A" }
    type B = { type: "B" }
    type X = A | B

    type Batch<T extends X> = { type: T["type"]; batch: Array<T> }
    type BatchA = Batch<A>
    type BatchB = Batch<B>
    type BatchTypes = BatchA | BatchB

    function find(x: X, list: Array<BatchTypes>) {
        return list.find(item => item.type === x.type)
    }

    function enqueue(x: X, queue: Array<BatchTypes>) {
        const result = find(x, queue)
        if (result) {
            result.batch.push(x)
        } else {
            queue.push({type: x.type, batch:[x]})
        }
    }

    let a: A
    let b: B
    let queue: Array<BatchTypes>

    enqueue(a, queue)
    enqueue(b, queue)
```

The problem here lies in `enqueue` because result a union of both types. When I try to overload the types, result is resolved properly but there's an issue with the first argument of `find` and pushing a new batch to the queue:

```
    function find(x: A, list: Array<BatchTypes>): BatchA
    function find(x: B, list: Array<BatchTypes>): BatchB
    function find(x: X, list: Array<BatchTypes>) {
        return list.find(item => item.type === x.type)
    }

    function enqueue(x: A, queue: Array<BatchTypes>)
    function enqueue(x: B, queue: Array<BatchTypes>)
    function enqueue(x: X, queue: Array<BatchTypes>) {
        const result = find(x, queue)
        if (result) {
            result.batch.push(x)
        } else {
            queue.push({ type: x.type, batch: [x] })
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if there's a better way of clarifying this question.

---

Given @artem's answer, I've gotten closer:

```
    function find<T extends X>(x: T, list: Array<BatchTypes>): Batch<T> {
        return <Batch<T>>list.find(item => item.type === x.type)
    }

    function enqueue<T extends X>(x: T, queue: Array<BatchTypes>) {
        const result = find(x, queue)
        if (result) {
            result.batch.push(x)
        } else {
            queue.push({ type: x.type, batch: [x] })
        }
    }
```

But there's still an issue with `queue.push`.

---

Maybe this is a more concise example of demonstrating the current issue:

```
    type A = { type: "A" }
    type B = { type: "B" }
    type X = A | B

    let list: Array<Array<A> | Array<B>>

    function append<T extends X>(x: T) {
        list.push([x])
    }

    function append2(x: X) {
        list.push([x])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding [overload declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for `find`:

```
type A = {type: "A"}
type B = {type: "B"}
type X = A | B

function find(a: A, list: Array<X>): A;
function find(a: B, list: Array<X>): B;
function find(x: X, list: Array<X>) {
    return list.find(item => item.type === x.type)
}

let a: A;
let b: B;
let x = [a, b];

let a1 = find(a, x); // inferred as A
let b1 = find(b, x); // inferred as B
```

If `find` return type will always be the same as  the type of its first argument, you can use single generic overload declaration to avoid repeating:

```
function find<T extends X>(x: T, list: Array<X>): T;
function find(x: X, list: Array<X>) {
    return list.find(item => item.type === x.type)
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there any ways of iterating through all the union types in X to do that overloading?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to iterate, but you can use single generic declaration to express that `find` return type and first argument type are the same. I updated the answer.

Comment: Check out the edit I just added -- turns out this is only part of the way there...

Comment: I don't know how to make TypeScript to do case analysis along the lines "if `x` is `A | B` then `{type: x.type}` must be `{type: 'A'} | {type: 'B'}`, not `{type: 'A' | 'B'}` without having explicit switch statement listing all alternatives in the code. Need to think more about it.

Comment: Yes! that's exactly what i'm wrangling with. Thanks for the effort!